# Automatically saving firebase function logs - best practices

Tags: firebase, logging, google-cloud-functions

Firebase cloud function logs seem to have quite a short shelf life with no way of changing it. So I was thinking of how to store older logs. I've tried adding a sink into bigquery, but it didn't seem to work as can't see/access any logs anywhere in bigquery despite a sink being set up.

Has anyone come across any simple way of automating storage of all firebase logs somewhere? It doesn't have to be bigquery, just somewhere where old function logs can be looked up easily if need be.

Answer (score 0):

All Firebase project are as well Google Cloud Procject and are available trough [GCP console](https://console.cloud.google.com/). In Monitoring you will find Stockdiver which is more extensive tool.

Please take a look at [this Solution article](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/design-patterns-for-exporting-stackdriver-logging). Export to BigQuery is even mentioned there as Stockdriver feature. So I guess it should be possible for your function without any problems.

General info of Monitoring on GCP is [here](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=emea-pl-all-en-dr-bkws-all-all-trial-e-gcp-1008073&utm_content=text-ad-none-any-DEV_c-CRE_167406679178-ADGP_Hybrid%20%7C%20AW%20SEM%20%7C%20BKWS%20~%20EXA_M:1_PL_EN_Management_Stackdriver_google%20stackdriver-KWID_43700016296236416-kwd-273465449890-userloc_9067437&utm_term=KW_google%20stackdriver-ST_google%20stackdriver&ds_rl=1242853&ds_rl=1245734&ds_rl=1245734&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI-I-s7bj45gIVjMreCh1dPgX_EAAYASAAEgKlhfD_BwE#documentation).

I hope it will help!